# Supervisor running on background but jobs are getting failed immediately

Tags: php, queue, supervisord, beanstalkd, laravel-5

I've setup a [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) successfully (`CentOS release 6.6`) for [beanstalk](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) queue and it was working before but suddenly after changing the password, it's not working anymore. I did it (setup) as `root` user but now whenever I add a job in the `queue` it fails and following trace is available in the log file:

```
2014-12-03 00:45:36,017 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2014-12-03 00:45:36,017 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2014-12-03 00:45:36,017 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2014-12-03 00:45:36,017 INFO supervisord started with pid 31309
2014-12-03 00:45:37,022 INFO spawned: 'queue' with pid 31317
2014-12-03 00:45:38,023 INFO success: queue entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Right now the `supervisord.conf` contains following configuration:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=info
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false
minfds=1024
minprocs=200

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock

[program:queue]
command=/usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:listen --tries=3 --timeout=86400 --sleep=60

directory=/home/***/www/*** // Real path removed for this question
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
```

I've tried everything as I could, restarted the `program` and reloaded the `supervisor` several times but no luck. What can I do now to make it working again?

**Update:** If I run the `php artisan queue:work` from terminal manually then it works on foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ ps aux | grep artisan  # get artisan PID
$ sudo kill -2 <PID>
$ ps aux | grep artisan  # verify artisan has shutdown properly - if not use kill -9 in previous step
```

Sometimes `supervisorctl` has problems shutting down processes. It may be because the process doesn't listen to SIGINT/SIGTERM or because the process has hung. In either case `kill -9` should brute force kill it, and then you can use `supervisorctl start program`